# How to sync G Suite users with an Active Directory Domain Controller?

Tags: active-directory, identity, okta, google-workspace

We're developing an all-in-one cloud desktop solution for businesses.

In our infrastructure, every business has his own Active Directory DC and Remote Desktop server. Almost every client we have uses G Suite for their e-mail and documents. This works well and we're not looking to change it.

**The problem**

As we are providing an all-in-one solution, we want all our users from G Suite to sync *to* our domain controller. Google provides a sync tool (GCDS) which does sync users, but the wrong way.

Before we switched to Google, we used Okta as the identity provider. Okta has a tool to sync users the *right* way, but we didn't find such a tool at Google.

To clarify: the domain controller is, in fact, a 'slave', were Okta/Google is the 'master'. We are not searching for another directory service, as ADDS is required for a well-working Windows-based Remote Desktop solution.

Is there any way to sync users from G Suite to ADDS?

Thanks :)

*PS: It does not have to be a free solution, per se, but we prefer it.*